# MediaWiki: How to extend user class?

Tags: php, mediawiki, wiki

I'm trying to extend the user class of MediaWiki by adding some methods like `$user->getNameOfPet()`. E.g. the extension `Article_Class_Extended` extends the default article class using a hook:

```
    $wgExtensionFunctions[] = "wfArticleExSetup";

    function wfArticleExSetup()
    {
            global $wgHooks;
            $wgHooks['ArticleFromTitle'][] = 'wfArticleExInit';     
    }

    function wfArticleExInit( &$title, &$article )
    {
            // What really counts is what is returned in $article.
            $GLOBALS['wgArticle'] = new ArticleExClass( $title, $article, true );
            return true;    
    }
```

Is there a way for extending the user class in a similar way?
I'm using MediaWiki 1.16.5.

Comment: 1.16 is quite old. Keep it up-to-date.

Comment: 1.16 is actually no longer maintained.

Comment: @GolezTrol and poke: I know that this is a quite old version of MediaWiki but it is not possible to update it at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think from your settings file you could call

```
RequestContext::getMain()->setUser(new User());
```

I've used this to force an 'empty' (not logged in) user. If this call lets you set a user object, you should be able to feed it a User descendant as well. This line is similar to the line in Setup.php that sets the $wgUser global.

Comment: This would work fine for MW 1.18 or newer but does not for 1.16.5 because there is no ``RequestContext``.

Comment: Ah. I'm sorry about that. In that case I wouldn't know. :-/ But I urge you to upgrade. Olders versions may have known leaks, but above all, it gets harder to upgrade with time, because more changes means more files and database changes. If you make a copy of your Wiki, you can try out the upgrade process in a test environment, so you will know what exact steps you need to make to upgrade.

Comment: However, your answer was helpful, so I will accept it (will help me later with MW 1.20). There are hundreds of people working with that wiki every day. So getting those things to work has highest priority although that wiki may be outdated. Afterwards there will be time to try out updating. There will be some issues with the extensions.

Comment: This isn't a 100% fool-proof method to use if you extend the User class. For example, during the login process it calls the User class statically; User::addToDatabase() so it avoids your extended class all together. Just something to be aware of. (this comment is regarding 1.19.1)

Comment: @JamieTaniguchi Good point, although that's only a problem if you need to override any of the static methods.